# What is the Tk command which does the same as clicking on the x button of a window?

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit, window-managers

There are command like `wm minimize *window*` and `wm maximize *window*` which minimize and maximize the window respectively, but there is nothing like `wm exit *window*`.

I need a Tk command which does EXACTLY the same as clicking on the x button, particularly emits the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` signal. So the `destroy *window*` command doesn't fit the needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a command. You will have to call your function directly and then destroy the window.

Comment: Well, `event generate` would do it, except that that can only target Tk windows and not the window manager, and you can't use it to generate property changes (the protocols mechanism is non-trivial).